# Minimum server.js required to run react/redux application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, server, webpack

I've built my project with webpack using babel for ES6 transpilation with following presets:

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
}
```

And webpack production config looking in the following way:

```
var path = require('path');
var node_modules_dir = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

module.exports = {
  entry: [ path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js') ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: [node_modules_dir],
      loader: 'babel'
    },
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
      exclude: [node_modules_dir],
      loader: 'url?limit=100000'
    },
    {
      test: /\.svg$/,
      exclude: [node_modules_dir],
      loader: 'svg-url-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: [node_modules_dir],
      loader: 'style!css!sass'
    }]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'] }
};
```

And I would like to now deploy it to the server. Production ready files are located in the `dist` folder, so:

```
dist/
  index.html
  bundle.js
```

I'm mentioning this, as I need my entry point to be `dist/index.html`.

As I have never deployed previously I'm not sure how my server.js file should look, after some research it seems that I need to use http server or express server, with some babel transpiration as well for es6 syntax.

What would be a minimum setup that can be used?

Comment: Both react and redux are client-side.  You can serve this with any HTTP server including something as simple as python SimpleHTTPServer,  If you want to use nodejs then google "http server nodejs" and this should lead you to plenty of related resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React/redux is client-side, i.e. the browser executes your code, the server only needs to get it there.

Your server does not need to do anything clever, like transpiling, as your build process has already done that and created a 'bundle' ready to be executed in a browser. As such, a quick static server, such as one using Nginx, Apache or Varnish, needs only to serve the contents of your `dist` folder.

Node, Python, whatever, can be used, but you dont need them, you only need to serve files.

Comment: So, how come this approach doesn't work by simply opening index file in the browser? (from my computer)

Comment: does your index.html or js file contain any external links? such as fonts, images or maybe dependencies via a cdn of some sort? file protocol will not allow external links. Running from file:// and from a local server are not the same thing. What error do you get?

Comment: Removed google fonts as I was including them via cdn, however nothing is showing up and error I'm getting is this one: `Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///../index.html' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null'.`

Comment: oh, ok, yeah that makes sense. doesnt really matter in the context of your question though. you're serving from file, using nginx etc is not the same. it is related to security issues in your browser surrounding serving from the file protocol. by using a server, it will no longer be from file, even if local.

Comment: I have the same React/redux code running in a webpack dev server and apache, but the apache version doesn't load any styles etc. Any ideas what I ned to do to setup Apache to run a react with Redux code?

Comment: Whatever style sheet/s your webpack build outputs, you just need to make sure that Apache can serve that file and that your html/s (or from JS) includes the path to that file. I don't use webpack but I suspect it manages the CSS pipeline for you, possibly also appending the link tag to the html.